# puzzle in python of removing particular characters from the inserted string

Tags: django, python-3.x, data-science

Is there any other substitue for this code where i do not use random function so that the testing compiler can remove any character it wants. also a constraint is given that only atmost 2 characters can be removed from the string

```
    def puzzle(s):
    import random
    # s= str(input("string is : "))
    l = [0, 1, 2]
    lenthofstring = len(s)
    n = random.choice(l)
    # print(n)
    for x in range(0, n + 1):
        p = random.choice(s)
        # print(p)
        s1 = s.replace(p, '')
    # print(s,s1)

    # print(len(s),len(s1))

    if len(s1)<len(s) / 2:
        return True
    else:
        return False


print(puzzle(s=str(input())))
```